# Can we display CVI result on raspberry pi webpage?

Tags: image-processing, raspberry-pi3

Good evening. I'm Raash. I want to do a fish  detection program using Raspberry Pi. For example , my camera will capture the image of the aquarium and will process the image and detect the fish in the aquarium(Like rectangle box drawn on fish). I would like to do live image processing. My question is ,is it possible to display the image processing result on the webpage host by my raspberry pi? For example the user will login to the webpage host by my pi and able to see the live fish detect program running. Is it possible? I know we can create an application to display the result but can we with webpage?

Comment: I guess you would need to look at WebRTC for this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8MglSka1Y4 is related

Comment: Bro thanks alo bro :D really appreciate that